# Fill missing values based on group

Tags: performance, r

I am trying to fill values based on group, in my case `id`. I would like to fill the missing values according to the available `date` info for each `id`.

> ```
>    id  date
> 1   1 23-04
> 2   1 23-04
> 3   1  <NA>
> 4   1  <NA>
> 5   2 24-04
> 6   2  <NA>
> 7   2  <NA>
> 8   2  <NA>
> 9   3 23-04
> 10  3  <NA>
> 11  3  <NA>
> 12  3  <NA>
> 13  4  <NA>
> 14  4  <NA>
> 15  4  <NA>
> 16  4  <NA>
> ```

What I need is:

> ```
>     id  date
> 1   1 23-04
> 2   1 23-04
> 3   1 23-04
> 4   1 23-04
> 5   2 24-04
> 6   2 24-04
> 7   2 24-04
> 8   2 24-04
> 9   3 23-04
> 10  3 23-04
> 11  3 23-04
> 12  3 23-04
> 13  4  <NA>
> 14  4  <NA>
> 15  4  <NA>
> 16  4  <NA>
> ```

I figured out a loop, but I would like to avoid it because my data has 23 millions rows:

```
for(i in 2:nrow(dta)){
  if(dta$id[i-1] == dta$id[i])
  {
    dta$date[i] = dta$date[i-1]
  }
}
```

I cannot figure out how to translate this into dplyr syntax:

```
dta = structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"
), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("23-04", 
"24-04"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", "date"), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R this is usually solved using the `na.locf` (Last Observation Carried Forward) function from the [zoo](https://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo) package.

See also here:

- [Fill in NA based on the last non-NA value for each group in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207162/fill-in-na-based-on-the-last-non-na-value-for-each-group-in-r)
- [Using dplyr window-functions to make trailing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340150/using-dplyr-window-functions-to-make-trailing-values)

---

```
# test data
x <- read.table(text="id;date
1;23-04
1;23-04
1;NA
1;NA
2;24-04
2;NA
2;NA
2;NA
3;23-04
3;NA
3;NA
3;NA
4;NA
4;NA
4;NA
4;NA", header=TRUE, sep=";")

library("dplyr")
library("zoo")

x %>% group_by(id) %>% transmute(date=na.locf(date, na.rm=FALSE))
Source: local data frame [16 x 2]
Groups: id

   id  date
1   1 23-04
2   1 23-04
3   1 23-04
4   1 23-04
5   2 24-04
6   2 24-04
7   2 24-04
8   2 24-04
9   3 23-04
10  3 23-04
11  3 23-04
12  3 23-04
13  4    NA
14  4    NA
15  4    NA
16  4    NA
```

Another option are rolling self-joins supported by the [data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/package=data.table) package (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23341304/172261)).

Comment: interesting I will try it on the whole sample

Comment: It would be great to see how we can do it with data.table and nomatch=roll or roll=Inf.  I'm not able to find any example.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for packages. This is easily and efficiently done with basic syntax.

```
# Create data.table

dtk <- data.table( var=c(NA,NA,1,NA,NA,2,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,4,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,6,7,NA,NA), group=c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B"))

# Backward fill

dtk[,order:= (1:.N)];
setorder(dtk,-order);
dtk[, var_backward_fill := var[1], by=  .( group , cumsum(!is.na(var))) ];
setorder(dtk, order);
dtk[,order:= NULL];

# Forward fill

dtk[, var_forward_fill  := var[1], by=  .( group , cumsum(!is.na(var))) ]
```